# Enable addon error in user preferences

Tags: rendering, add-on

[image]

Hey guys, just a quick one. I'm trying to enable this addon in Blender 2.8 (which it's designed for) and I'm getting this call back error. I have no idea what it means or how to fix it.

My addon paths are located in /2.80/scripts/addons/Arnold & /2.80/scripts/addons/brnold.

I enabled the environemnt variables in windows 10 too as required the instructions: https://github.com/tyler-furby/Arnold-For-Blender

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: seems to be a known issue https://github.com/tyler-furby/Arnold-For-Blender/issues/16